# Finding an array of parent objects whose childs meet condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app which has Countries, Clients and Orders. Order belongs to Client, Clients belongs to Country, Client has many Orders and Country has many Clients.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
    belongs_to :country
end
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
    has many :clients
end
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :total
    belongs_to :client
end
```

I'm trying to figure out the fastest way to get, in a Controller, an array of Clients from a given Country who have at least one order meeting a certain condition. For example: Clients from Spain who have at least one order with a total above $100.

I'm thinking I should use Joins, but don't know how to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to join on `:orders`.

```
c = Country.find(id_for_spain)
filtered_clients = c.clients.joins(:orders).where("orders.total > ?", 100)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, much cleaner than the loop I had before.

Comment: Ha, and *much* faster than a loop.